# Data preprocessing for Named Entity Recognition?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm working on a Named Entity Recognition on resume dataset and we have entities like dates, phone, email etc.,,

And I'm working how to preprocess those entities. I'm currently adding a space after each puncuation like this,

```
DAVID B-Name
John I-Name
, O
IT O

Washington B-Address
, I-Address
DC I-Address
( B-Phone
107 I-Phone
) I-Phone
155
- I-Phone
4838 I-Phone
david B-Email
. I-Email
John I-Email
@ I-Email
gmail I-Email
. I-Email
com I-Email
```

But I'm starting to question the process on how to handle such text during inference. I'm assuming even at inference we have to preprocess text using same process that is adding a space after each puncuation isn't it?

But it won't be so readable right?

For example at inference I have to provide input text like `test @ example . com?` which is not readable isn't it? It only be able to predict entities in such format.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're trying to deal with is called [tokenization](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/tokenization-1.html). To deal with the formatting issue that you raise, often frameworks will extract the tokens from the underlying text in a way preserves the original text, such as keeping track of the character starts and ends for each token.

For instance, [SpaCy](https://spacy.io) in Python returns an object that stores all of this information:

```py
import spacy
from pprint import pprint

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("DAVID John, IT\nWashington, DC (107) 155-4838 david.John@gmail.com")
pprint([(token.text, token.idx, token.idx + len(token.text)) for token in doc])
```

output:

```
[('DAVID', 0, 5),
 ('John', 6, 10),
 (',', 10, 11),
 ('IT', 12, 14),
 ('\n', 14, 15),
 ('Washington', 15, 25),
 (',', 25, 26),
 ('DC', 27, 29),
 ('(', 30, 31),
 ('107', 31, 34),
 (')', 34, 35),
 ('155', 36, 39),
 ('-', 39, 40),
 ('4838', 40, 44),
 ('david.John@gmail.com', 45, 65)]
```

You could either do the same sort of thing for yourself (e.g. keep a counter as you add spaces) or use an existing tokenizer (such as SpaCy, CoreNLP, tensorflow, etc.)

Comment: I want to use [flairNLP](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair) for training the ner model but it doesn't support spacy annotation schema. It requires IOB annotation. How can I convert this into similar to my input above in the question

Comment: @user_12 it looks like you can either join the text (so the above plus `text = " ".join((token.text for token in doc))`) or flairNLP has a built in classifier you can use (`sentence = Sentence('The grass is green.', use_tokenizer=True)`) https://github.com/flairNLP/flair/blob/master/resources/docs/TUTORIAL_1_BASICS.md#tokenization